# Match multiple columns of a dataframe and replace values

Tags: r

How can I replace the `NA` values in the column `three` in `A` with the matching rows' values from column `three` in `B`?

```
A
   one                 two three
1    A ram 1500 pickup 4wd     0
2    B               jetta     0
3    C         4runner 4wd  <NA>
4    D     mountaineer 4wd     5
5    E         range rover  <NA>
6    F ram 1500 pickup 4wd     0
7    G               jetta     0
8    H         4runner 4wd  <NA>
9    I     mountaineer 4wd     5
10   J         range rover     0
11   K ram 1500 pickup 4wd     0
12   L               jetta  <NA>
13   M         4runner 4wd     0
14   N     mountaineer 4wd     0
15   O         range rover  <NA>
16   P ram 1500 pickup 4wd     0
17   Q               jetta     5
18   R         4runner 4wd     5
19   S     mountaineer 4wd  <NA>
20   T         range rover  <NA>



B
   one             two three
3    C     4runner 4wd     1
5    E     range rover     1
8    H     4runner 4wd     1
12   L           jetta     1
15   O     range rover     1
19   S mountaineer 4wd     1
20   T     range rover     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your both tables are data frames:

```
C <- merge(A, B, by = c("one", "two"), all.x = TRUE)
C$three.x <- ifelse(is.na(C$three.x), C$three.y, C$three.x)
C$three.y <- NULL
names(C)[3] <- "three"
```

Comment: if was trying to use the ifelss() and now I get the idea that the _both the yes and no argument should come from the same object_,  let me try that.  Thanks